# WordPress/CSS Identical pages/font-families but look different

Tags: css, wordpress

Any ideas on this one?
I have 2 identical wordpress pages (one was a production and another is dublicated with first one's backup). However, fonts on both pages look differently even if inspecting shows no difference between them.
The only thing, that is different, apart that it is not the same url is that one domain is using SSL other is not.

How it looks:

Production:

[Production enviroment(SSL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwVFV.jpg)

Test:

[Test enviroment (no SSL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCDxC.jpg)

Both enviroments use same css:

```
font-family: futura-light;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 400;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
```

Comment: One of your environments will be cached. Hit `CTRL` + `F5`. If that doesn't work, try `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `R`.

Comment: It seems that the font is not loaded in the one of the cases and what you see is a fallback option. If importing font remotely make sure that the you load font with https when having ssl and http when having no ssl.

Comment: LOL, was looking for an issue for ages. But looks like the problem was -> when I migrated, plugin, that was responsible for fonts was looking for a directory from primary site and did not find it. Yes @user3127632, it was the case of fallback option. Have not checked browser console before, but all needed info was there. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad that helped :). I added the comment as answer. Please mark it as correct answer if you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the font is not loaded in the one of the cases and what you see is a fallback option. If importing font remotely make sure that the you load font with https when having ssl and http when having no ssl.